# SAS - how to stop results tab opening in sas using code.

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-ods

I have the below code:

```
ods _all_ close;
ods csv file="filename.csv"
%macro mac_name (st, en=); 
  %do j=1 %to &en.;
  %let k=%eval(&j.+1);
      proc freq data=data_name;
        tables status&j. * status&k. / nocol norow nopercent missing;
      run;
  %end;
%mend;
%mac_name (st=1, en=%sysfunc(week(%sysfunc(today()), u)));
ods csv close;
```

which works fine.

The only problem is i don't want the results tab to open up, and this has to be done from within the code as i am to schedule the job.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand, if you are running it in batch there is no results tab to open or not open.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not running it in batch, I'd recommend using the ods noresults statement.  I've posted a simple, reproducible example using Sashelp.Cars below.  This was tested in windows SAS 9.4 only.

```
ods _all_ close;
ods noresults;  

ods csv file="filename.csv";
  proc print data=Sashelp.Cars; 

  run;

ods csv close; 
ods _all_ close;
```

Comment: Thanks. This didn't produce results, but still opened a results tab.

Comment: ods results off; ods results on; worked for me in the end